# Общенаучные или узкоспецильные термины?

Tags: стилистика, терминология, стили-речи

К чему отнести такие термины:

> **этимология, лингвистическое объяснение, диалект, суффикс, корень, звуковой облик**?

Я думаю, что это либо общенаучные термины, либо узкоспециальные:

> **Общенаучная терминология** выражает категории и понятия, принципиально и продуктивно применимые ко всем областям научного знания: *система, элемент, структура, функция, модель, парадигма.*

Судя по этому определению это скорее всего не общенаучные термины.

> **Узкоспециальные термины:** 1) термины именующие сферу деятельности, названия научных дисциплин, наименования проблем, решением которых занимаются конкретные науки и т. п.: *когнитивная лингвистика, фонология, теория речевых актов, семасиология;* 2) термины, именующие объект деятельности данной науки: *фонология – фонема, аллофоны, варианты фонемы, фонологическая парадигма;* 3) термины, именующие объект деятельности: *дискурсолог, лексиколог, фонетист;* 4) термины, именующие средства (орудия, процессы, методы) деятельности: *метод когнитивного картирования, метод стилистического эксперимента;* 5) термины, именующие продукты деятельности: полупроводниковые материалы, металлы, металлические сплавы, керметы, искусственные волокна, пластмассы, полимеры и пр.

Я склоняюсь к тому, что это узкоспециальные термины. А вы как думаете?

[Вот](http://booksonline.com.ua/view.php?book=28480&page=25) текст, в котором они употреблены.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что это предмет изучения лингвистики, всё-таки узкоспециальные лингвистические термины. Употреблены в научно-популярной статье.

Comment: Это лингвистические термины или узкоспециальные слова - одно из двух. Узкоспециальные да ещё лингвистические термины - это "масло масляное "  или тавтология. А в остальном я с Вами совершенно согласна.